# New Ubuntu 20.04 install doesn't recognize wifi adapter

Tags: drivers, wireless, gigabyte

Old mobo gave out so bought a new one. Got Ubuntu 20.04 installed on it since that's the USB I had lying around. To update etc I need to be online. I open up settings and it says no wifi adapter detected :(

Full specs:

- i5-12400
- 8gbx2 5200MT/s DDR5
- Z690I Aorus Ultra Lite mobo
- Samsung 970 EVO Plus SSD 1TB NVMe M.2

Here's the mobo info page: https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/Z690I-AORUS-ULTRA-LITE-rev-10/support#support-dl-bios

I have already flashed BIOS to version 23a which is the latest. I don't see any linux drivers in the download section. Any advice on what to do?

Comment: What is Ubuntu 20? There is no such desktop version. Try to boot with 22.04 and check if the wireless device is detected.

Comment: Don't forget the *year* products are specialist *snap only* products of the main *year.month* release intended for Cloud or IoT usage, they are smaller thus faster to boot & require less RAM, but are less powerful than the *year.month* server product it comes from, ie. 20 differs to 20.04.

Comment: The specifications page in your link says that the wireless is Intel® Wi-Fi 6 AX201. You can verify this with a terminal commad: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` This page suggests that it is included in kernel version 5.2 et seq: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html Perhaps there are informative clues in the log: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && sudo dmesg | grep iwl` Please edit your question to include the result of these commands.

Comment: I was installing Ubuntu 20.04 because that's what I had on hand. After plugging it in via ethernet it still wouldn't work so I reflashed the drive to 22.04 and it worked after that. I have no clue why.

Comment: If you were installing 20.04, why not say so, since 20 & 20.04 are different products (20 being the *snap* only version of 20.04, thus cannot perform all functions of 20.04, but the smaller system also has its advantages, esp. for cloud or IoT usage). Ubuntu has reserved the *year* format for *snap* only since 2016.  Please correct your question if you're using 20.04 & not 20

Comment: Sure thing will do. I didn't know there was a difference like that.

Comment: LTS releases of Ubuntu have kernel stack options; ie. GA is the most *stable* and default for Server installs, HWE provides the *enablement stack* so newer systems can get newer '*drivers*' (*drivers* being the common term for what are actually kernel modules; thus the kernel [stack] being used matters!).  Your question was devoid of kernel stack details, not even mentioning desktop/server - so we cannot even guess.  20.04 using HWE (5.15) will use the GA stack from 22.04 so you should be able to get 20.04 working too if using GA for 22.04; but you mention only release and not more...